# jsfiddle same codes display different results on server

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

html,

```
<p style="text-align:center">
            <label for="user">User</label>
            <input type="radio" name="kategori" id="user" value="user">
            <label for="admin">Admin</label>
            <input type="radio" name="kategori" id="admin" value="admin"></p>
```

css,

```
input{
    margin: 7px;
    }

input[type="radio"] {
    margin-left:30px;
}
```

I was trying to centered the radio buttons and it became like this in my wampserver,

[image]

so I tried my code again at jsfiddle and found that the form was perfect.

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g6AMB/)

why?

how can I manage this?

Comment: It looks like you're using a CSS reset somewhere else on the page.  That's just a guess but as a reminder, we already need to code for multplie device types, jsFiddle is a tool for testing concepts and not a reliable platform or device we calibrate our code or css to.

Comment: do you have any idea?